# How Should I proceed after adding Tab to my facebook Fan Page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using javascript SDK for adding tabs to my Facebook Fan page which is getting added properly.
  Now I have to pass an external link to newly added tab in my Facebook Fan page. Please let me know If anyone knows it. Below is the method I am calling to Add a Tab in my Facebook Fan page.

```js
 function uploadFb()
 {
FB.ui({
   method: 'pagetab',
     name: 'Deal Page',
            link: 'Externsl Url', //Can I pass my link like this?
            picture: 'Image url',
            caption: 'Test Page',  
 
  redirect_uri: '<My Redirect uri>'
}, function(response){
 
 alert(response);
}); 
  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is your third question regarding the same topic in 24h, and you didn't receive an answer, I think this should make you think that people don't understand what you want to to.

If you want to add your app to a Page Tab, then refer to the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#integrating